# SQL Server : converting Null date times

Tags: sql-server

I have a query in SSMS which is returning `1900-01-01`, how can I use a `CASE WHEN` accurately to replace `1900-01-01` with `''` (a blank not a null).

```
CAST(ISNULL(CAST(CONVERT(DATE, cmmt.[CmmtExpirationDate], 101) AS NVARCHAR(20)), '') AS DATE) AS [Cmmt Expiration Date]
```

Result:  `1900-01-01`

I tried this but no luck (terrible syntax):

```
CASE 
   WHEN (CAST(ISNULL(cast(convert(Date, cmmt.[CmmtExpirationDate] , 101) as nvarchar(20)), '') = '1900-01-01')
      THEN ''
      ELSE CAST(ISNULL(cast(convert(Date, cmmt.[CmmtExpirationDate] , 101) as nvarchar(20)),'') AS DATE
END
```

Comment: You can't. An empty string will force an implicit conversion to a datetime which is 1900-01-01. You have to remember that the datatype here is a date and an empty string is NOT a valid date. If you want to display an empty string when there is no date this should be done in the front end.

Comment: but you are trying to convert it to a `DATE` after all, and you can't have an empty string as a `DATE` (it converts it to `1900-01-01`)

Comment: What data type is `CmmtExpirationDate`?

Comment: Why not return NULL when there is no date instead of empty string. This way you wouldn't mess with return type or "with 1900-01-01" .  Just handle null value on client side properly.

Comment: @Heinzi The data type is listed in the table as [CmmtExpirationDate] [smalldatetime] NULL

Comment: @AXMIM while NULL is an easy find and replace in excel, I was hoping to find a way to prevent the user from doing this. This data pulll is an alternate to using the front-end BI tool

Answer (score 2):

The result of your expression needs to have a fixed data type. `DATE` is not possible, since `''` is not a valid date. `nvarchar(20)` would be an option, but that means that your result will be a string *even if* it is not `1900-01-01`.

Once you accept that, the solution is simple:

```
CASE WHEN cmmt.[CmmtExpirationDate] = '1900-01-01'
     THEN CONVERT(nvarchar(20), cmmt.[CmmtExpirationDate])
     ELSE CONVERT(nvarchar(20), '')
END
```

You might want to specify the [desired output format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) as a third parameter to the first `CONVERT` statement.

*(I assume that `CmmtExpirationDate` is of type `DATE`, because if it isn't, it should have been mentioned in the question.)*

Comment: It most likely isn't since the op is doing `CONVERT(DATE, cmmt.[CmmtExpirationDate], 101)`

Comment: I would use caution if converting dates to a string like this. If you do sorting on the client side you won't be able to accurately sort depending on the format of your date strings.

Comment: @Lamak: Well, if it's already a string, the solution is trivial `CASE WHEN ... = '1900-01-01' THEN ... ELSE '' END`.

Comment: @SeanLange: Yes. Obviously, returning a date and doing all the formatting on the client side is always preferable. Since I don't know the OP's use case, I assumed "good faith" and just answered the question as stated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use try_convert as below:

```
try_convert(date, case when datecolumn='' then null else datecolumn end)
```